# android error in recieving data from android to web

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to send data from android to web but i am not receiving it on web.
I guess the mistake is in php code. The database name is androidapi2 and it has two tables, one for login and one for data.

Here is code of php file DB_functions2.php :

```
    <?php
    class DB_Functions2 {
        private $conn;
        function __construct() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';

            $db = new Db_Connect();
            $this->conn = $db->connect();
        }
        // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }
        public function storeData($data) {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_data(data) VALUES($data))");

            $stmt->bind_param("s",$data);
            $result = $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->close();

                return $user_data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Following is the other php file data.php:

```
      <?php

    /**
     * @author Ravi Tamada
     * @link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ Complete tutorial
     */

    require_once 'include/DB_Functions2.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions2();

    // json response array
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);

    if (isset($_POST['data'])) {

        // receiving the post params

        $data = $_POST['data'];     
            $user_data = $db->storeData($data);
            if ($user_data) {

                $response["error"] = FALSE;

                $response["user_data"]["data"] = $user_data["data"];

                echo json_encode($response);
            } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your web server logs for the errors?

Answer (score 0):

In this row there is an extra closed parenthesis - after $data:

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_data(data) VALUES($data))");
```